# SQL select features within a polygon

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, polygon

I have the following code whick works fine:

```
select vissoort, count(1), ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(5.341248 51.615590)',4326):: geography, 2500)
from   visvangsten
where  st_intersects(visvangsten.locatie,
ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(5.3412480 51.615590)',4326):: geography, 2500))
group by vissoort
order by 2 desc
```

Now I want the same function but then selecting the features within a polygon instead of the circle/buffer.

I tried things like this but nothing worked:

```
select vissoort, count(1), ST_asText( ST_Polygon('LINESTRING(5.303 51.629, 5.387 51.626, 5.393 51.588, 5.281 51.592)'::geometry, 4326) )
from   visvangsten
where  st_contains(ST_asText( ST_Polygon('LINESTRING(5.303 51.629, 5.387 51.626, 5.393 51.588, 5.281 51.592)'::geometry, 4326) ), visvangsten.locatie);
group by vissoort
order by 2 desc limit 1
```

The database table looks like this:

| id ([PK]bigint) | datum(date) | vissoort(character varying) | locatie(geometry) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15729 | 2007-06-23 | Blankvoorn | 0101000...etc. |
| etc. | etc. | etc. | etc. |

Does someone know the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that to transform a LineString into a Polygon you need to have a closed ring - in other words, the first and last coordinate pairs **must be identical**. That being said, you can convert a LineString into a Polygon using the function [`ST_MakePolygon`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePolygon.html). The following example is probably what you're looking for:

[image: Data set inside the CTE]

```
WITH j (geom) AS (
  VALUES 
    (ST_MakePolygon('SRID=4326;LINESTRING(-4.59 54.19,-4.55 54.23,-4.52 54.19,-4.59 54.19)'::geometry)),
    (ST_Buffer('SRID=4326;LINESTRING(-4.59 54.19,-4.55 54.23,-4.52 54.19,-4.59 54.19)'::geometry,0.1))
)
SELECT ST_Contains(geom,'SRID=4326;POINT(-4.5541 54.2043)'::geometry) FROM j;

 st_contains 
-------------
 t
 t
(2 Zeilen)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! The following code was correct: select vissoort, count(1), ST_MakePolygon('SRID=4326;LINESTRING(5.303 51.629, 5.387 51.626, 5.393 51.588, 5.281 51.592, 5.303 51.629)'::geometry)
from visvangsten
where st_contains(ST_MakePolygon('SRID=4326;LINESTRING(5.303 51.629, 5.387 51.626, 5.393 51.588, 5.281 51.592, 5.303 51.629)'::geometry) , visvangsten.locatie)
group by vissoort
order by 2 desc